# passing arguments in onclick functions appended from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code which looks like the following,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var agr1='#19865 - testArg';
  var arg2=1856
  $('#dv_Test').append('<button onclick="testFunction('+ agr1 +','+ arg2 +')">Test</button>')
});
function testFunction(arg1, arg2) { 
  alert(arg1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dv_Test"></div>
```

here I am getting error like the following

```
testFunction(#19865 - testArg,1856)
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

and my string `agr1` doesn't have `""` with itself

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: But why are you using inline handlers? `$('<button />').click(function() { // access scope variables normally})`

Comment: this is just an example I am getting data from database and binding this to table

Comment: your inline arguments should be **strings** if they are meant to be so. In a nutshell, you need to escape them, hence the "invalid or unexpected token" exception.

Comment: @MumbaiWadala " I am getting data from database and binding this to table" it doesn't really matter if you have access to the data (and I assume you do :)) You don't need inline handlers in year 2019.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the `arg1` value is a string and needs to have quotes around it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var agr1 = '#19865 - testArg';
  var arg2 = 1856
  $('#dv_Test').append('<button onclick="testFunction(\'' + agr1 + '\',' + arg2 + ')">Test</button>')
});

function testFunction(arg1, arg2) {
  alert(arg1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dv_Test"></div>
```

*However* a much better way to do this would be to put those values in `data` attributes and add a single delegated event handler to handle all dynamically created buttons. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var agr1 = '#19865 - testArg';
  var arg2 = 1856
  var $div = $('#dv_Test').append('<button data-arg1="' + agr1 + '" data-arg2="' + arg2 + '">Test</button>');
  
  $div.on('click', 'button', function() {
    var $btn = $(this); 
    console.log($btn.data('arg1'), $btn.data('arg2'));
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dv_Test"></div>
```

Comment: thanks the second solution is really good and I will implement that.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You need to have quotes around the argument.Alternatively you can try template literals

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var agr1 = '#19865 - testArg';
  var arg2 = 1856
  $('#dv_Test').append(`<button onclick="testFunction('${agr1}','${arg2}' )">Test</button>`)
});

function testFunction(arg1, arg2) {
  alert(arg1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dv_Test"></div>
```